# Ubuntu software center is running slow on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, software-center

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are updates downloading so slow?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124631/why-are-updates-downloading-so-slow)

Similar to this post ( [Why is software slow to install using Ubuntu Software Center?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135527/why-is-software-slow-to-install-using-ubuntu-software-center) ) installing software on my laptop is taking *forever*.  I rarely get speeds faster than about 20 KB/sec.

I tried `sudo apt-get --purge --reinstall install software-center` as suggested in 
[Why is software slow to install using Ubuntu Software Center?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135527/why-is-software-slow-to-install-using-ubuntu-software-center)

But that did not speed things up for me.  Just updating the packages via `sudo apt-get update` is taking way longer than it should.  I was at home when I first had this issue, now I'm on a college campus with good internet, and it is still very slow