# Ubuntu Software frequently freezes in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, gnome-software

Almost every time when I try to open Ubuntu Software it freezes and goes black for a few seconds. Ubuntu Software hangs and does not respond when opened. The same thing occurs sometimes while using it.

Comment: Please see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/883955/ubuntu-software-center-is-very-slow/883959#883959)

Comment: A workaround might be to install and use the  Synaptic, `sudo apt install synaptic` and learn how to use it. It might be more difficult to learn, but it is powerful and reliable.

Answer (score 3):

1. Remove locked up instances of Ubuntu Software from memory.

   ```
   killall gnome-software
   ```
2. Remove the `~/.local/share/gnome-software` directory. It will be recreated the next time you open Ubuntu Software.

   ```
   rm -r ~/.local/share/gnome-software
   ```
3. Uninstall and reinstall gnome-software.

   ```
   sudo apt update  
   sudo apt upgrade  
   sudo apt purge gnome-software && sudo apt install gnome-software
   ```
4. Check occasionally if there is a little square orange notification icon in the Ubuntu Software menu bar next to **Updates**. If this little orange square icon appears, click on it to switch to a screen that shows available updates and install the updates.

Comment: I have done what you have written. Now apps are not installing. After clicking "install" button "waiting to install" icon is added to that side bar.

Comment: Try installing a simple package like GtkHash which is only 158.7 kB. Close the terminal and open Ubuntu Software. Click the GtkHash icon in the search results to show the GtkHash screen. On the GtkHash screen click the Install button. A thin bright orange progress line will appear at the bottom of the Install button, and one or two seconds later GtkHash will be installed. If you have to press the Install button 2 or 3 times to start it installing, do it. Then check in the Dash if GtkHash has been successfully installed.

Comment: No. Not installing. I have pressed the install button several times. When I press it for first time an icon added to side panel showing that small progress bar. But not installing actually. No progress.