# GNOME software center hangs when searching for software

Tags: software-center, 20.10, flatpak

Running Ubuntu 20.10.

My software center hangs whenever I search for a software using the magnifying glass.

I have the flatpak extension enabled, it that's relevant.

Comment: I have had this in the past and a `killall snap-store` on the command line (then re-start) always fixes it for me. I usually do that anyway after closing the store as for whatever reason the snap-store process stays running in the background and uses a LOT of memory.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu Software Center is very slow](https://askubuntu.com/questions/883955/ubuntu-software-center-is-very-slow)

Answer (score 0):

For me, disabling "App Search" for not needed apps fixed the hanging.

To do that open the Gnome Settings -> Search -> Disable apps one by one until you find the one that causes the hanging.

[image]