# Ubuntu GUI Software Center (Snap store) very slow when searching

Tags: software-center, snap, gui, search

My Ubuntu Software center (Snap Store) is very slow when searching software, even when the software is not available. I using it logged in and tried several mirrors (local, USA, Europe) and the recommended mirrors after test.

However when suing snap search in the terminal command line (snap find *software_name*) is fast, I'm not sure why only the GUI version is slow.

Setup config:

- Ubuntu 20.04,
- Ubuntu Software 3.38.1,
- Laptop Lenovo Ideapad 3i
- Processor: i7-10750H
- 8Gb RAM, SSD

[image: Snap store config Ubuntu Software]

[Snap store config Other Software](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ax2sG.png)

Comment: Using `snap find` is quite an efficient process. However, Software Center is a larger, more complex beast. It has to load and parse a lot more data then the command line tool. You could file a bug in launchpad.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu Software Center is very slow](https://askubuntu.com/questions/883955/ubuntu-software-center-is-very-slow)